# How to make redelivery of messages work with topics in Azure Service Bus using Masstransit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azureservicebus, masstransit

I am trying to use UseDelayedRedelivery() for a particular subscription of my topic but I recently came across the fact that Subscription endpoints do not support redelivery.

How do I configure in my Startup.cs to make sure the delayed redelivery mechanism works for a topic?

Answer (score 1):

As you have found out, delayed redelivery does not work with topic subscriptions, as a subscription cannot be addressed directly in Azure Service Bus.

Delayed redelivery only works with queues.

If Azure updates their API to allow a message to be abandoned with a delay, MassTransit will be updated to use that feature to delay redelivery of the message.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. If you could suggest me the best way to handle a message that is not being consumed from a topic due to an external service being down for a long interval?

Comment: Long-time is what redelivery is designed for, but you need to use a receive endpoint (not a subscription endpoint).